# Simplifying symbolic expression with Heaviside step function

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic

When inputing

```
Integrate[HeavisideTheta[s - t], {s, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> {t > 0}]
```

Mathematica correctly simplifies if to

> -(-1 + t) HeavisideTheta[1 - t]

even though I did not explicitly ask it to Simplify. However, if I include an undefined function of the variable integrated over, x[s], Mathematica returns a wrong (or, rather, incomplete) result:

```
Integrate[HeavisideTheta[s - t] x[s], {s, 0, 1},  Assumptions -> {t > 0}]
```

> ConditionalExpression[0, t > 1]

Is there any way to fix this, e.g. leaving the expression unsimplified in the cases where indeed no simplifications can be made a priori?

Comment: Can you explain what answer you expect to see?

Comment: It would be enough to leave it unevaluated, in such a way that if I then assign the function x[s] and Simplify I get the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to define your integral as a function, which you can then call with your desired x[s]:

```
myHeavy[x_] := Integrate[HeavisideTheta[s - t] x, {s, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> {t > 0}];
```

Now, when you want to call this with a function x[s] = s^2, you evaluate

```
myHeavy[s^2]
```

To evaluate with Sin[s]

```
myHeavy[Sin[s]]
```

These seem to return plausible answers.